# In ZFS RAID 6 implementation, why certain shifts are ⊕, but not the others?

Tags: computer-science, computer-arithmetic

[ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#ZFS%27s_approach:_RAID-Z_and_mirroring) is a computer filesystem, which has an implementation of the RAID 6. I understand the [simplified example of the RAID 6 implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#Simplified_parity_example) in Wikipedia, which each data chunk D is bit-shifted by a different amount.

In ZFS RAID 6 (aka RAID-Z2) implementation (summarised in a developer [blog post](http://dtrace.org/blogs/ahl/2006/06/18/double-parity-raid-z/), the algorithm is based on [H. Peter Anvin's paper](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/hpa/raid6.pdf), as well as [the comment in source code](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/master/module/zfs/vdev_raidz.c#L64-L80)), y<sub>0</sub> through y<sub>7</sub>, which are multiplications by 2, means shifting of bits in binary.

However what I do not understand is, why y<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>, and y<sub>4</sub> are particularly ⊕ (exclusive-or) by x<sub>7</sub>, while the rest five do not?

Answer (score 1):

After study for a few more times, I understand a bit more. Simply say, why certain shifts are exclusive-or while the rest do not? **This is the *carefully chosen linear feedback shift register* algorithm.**

Quote from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#General_parity_system):

> General parity system
>
> It is possible to support a far greater number of drives by choosing the parity function more carefully.
> ...
>
> The effect of g i {\displaystyle g^{i}} g^{i} can be thought of as the action of a carefully chosen linear feedback shift register on the data chunk.[30] Unlike the bit shift in the simplified example, which could only be applied k {\displaystyle k} k times before the encoding began to repeat, applying the operator g {\displaystyle g} g multiple times is guaranteed to produce m = 2 k − 1 {\displaystyle m=2^{k}-1} {\displaystyle m=2^{k}-1} unique invertible functions, which will allow a chunk length of k {\displaystyle k} k to support up to 2 k − 1 {\displaystyle 2^{k}-1} 2^{k}-1 data pieces.

With a carefully chosen LFSR algorithm, among k-bits, it allows us to produce far more than k unique deviations.

Back to the [H. Peter Anvin's paper](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/hpa/raid6.pdf), the x's in the paper are bits (of a byte) while shifting and XOR 0001 1100 (of x<sub>7</sub>) produces the next shifted byte. From point 6 through point 12 should be proving that this shifting and XOR 0001 1100 algorithm would produce 255 unique deviations. (For this part I do not understand well about its proof as Mathematics is not my expertise. Should anyone could explain this would compose a better answer than mine.)

This is cross verified by the [ZFS RAID source code](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/master/module/zfs/vdev_raidz.c).

> In C, multiplying by 2 is therefore ((a << 1) ^ ((a & 0x80) ? 0x1d : 0)).

a is a byte. It is shifted and XOR 0001 1100, i.e. 0x1d (of x<sub>7</sub>), to produce the next byte.

> We provide a mechanism to perform the field multiplication
> operation on a  * 64-bit value all at once rather than a byte at a
> time. This works by  * creating a mask from the top bit in each byte
> and using that to  * conditionally apply the XOR of 0x1d.

However neither `VDEV_RAIDZ_MUL_2(x)` nor `VDEV_RAIDZ_MUL_4(x)` is used in the source code. Instead it uses a less trivial `VDEV_RAIDZ_64MUL_2`. This would require further calculation to prove and understand this part. Yet this might be a scope of programming more than mathematics.

Comment: The key is that a byte is not viewed as an element of the ring $\Bbb Z/256\Bbb Z$, but as an element of the field $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1)$